# Как отследить в React js когда загрузился весь компонент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как отследить в React js когда загрузился компонент полностью с картинками, видео, 3д обзорами, описанием и тд..?

ComponentDidMount не подходит. В ходе загрузки фотографий и более тяжелого контента все прыгает по мере загрузки

Answer (score 1):

[`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) - метод вызывается один раз после рендеринга компонента. Этот метод должен подойти, если вы не использовали рендеринга c помощью вспомогательных функций внутри метода `render()` и не использовали стрелочных функций внутри него. Пара полезных замечаний (источнк указан в конце ответа):

> **Замечание #1:** Использование `Function.prototype.bind` в рендере создает новую функцию каждый раз, когда компонент отображает, что
> может иметь последствия для производительности.
>
> **Замечание #2:** Использование стрелочной функции в рендере создает новую
> функцию каждый раз, когда компонент отображает, что может иметь
> последствия для производительности.

На просторах enSO имеется ответ на похожий вопрос [React “after render” code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26559473/5275890) - тут используется как раз `componentDidMount()`. Однако есть и другой подход: [Use `requestAnimationFrame` to ensure that your code is run after render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28748160/5275890) - тут предлагают использовать `window.requestAnimationFrame`. Однако и это еще не все, можно придумать своего рода хак в виде таймера и установки отложенного запуска через [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Однако я настоятельно рекомендую пересмотреть метод рендеринга, произвести рефаторинг кода, по мере необходимости ввести переменные в стейт компонента в виде параметра `loading`. Для примера, в конструкторе кладем `loading: true` далее внутри  `componentDidMount()` мы что-то подгружаем и на колбэк окончания загрузки ставим вызов анонимного метода, внутри которого меняем стейт и ставим `loading: false`, что вызовет ререндер компоента. А внутри рендера добавим простое условие с проверкой на значение из `loading`. Пример кода:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    data: null,
    loading: true, // для отображения загрузки
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  // загрузка какого-то контента
  loadingData
    .then((result) => {
      this.setState({ data: result, loading: false }); // загрузка завершена, данные есть
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({ data: {}, loading: false }); // загрузка завершена, данных нет
      console.error(error);
    });
}

render() {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return (<p>Loading...</p>); // отображение загрузки
  }

  return (<MyComponent data={this.state.data}>); // отображение результата
}
```

Это на тот случай, если проблема в загрузке данных и в их отображении после рендеринга. Однако, если Вы разбили рендеринг на несколько частей - нужно определять конкретные места рендеринга и добавлять колбэки на определенные части кода. Так как ваш вопрос не включает достаточного количества кода - мой ответ будет немного общим.

Также, можно добавить один слушатель на событие `load` внутрь `componentDidMount()`. Все просто:

```
componentDidMount() {
   document.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
      alert('page is fully loaded!');
   });
}
```

Ну, конечно, лучше пересмотреть свой метод рендеринга.

Пара полезных ссылок:

- [React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)
- [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)
- [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
- [WindowTimers.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)
- [Загрузка документа: DOMContentLoaded, load, beforeunload, unload](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)
- [Passing Functions to Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Comment: К сожалению, `DOMContentLoaded` не дожидается загрузки всего контента, он вызывается, когда распарсен весь `html`, но даже `css` может еще загружаться https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: надо использовать событие `load` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event